# Managing 3rd Party Javascript Libraries Across Projects

Tags: javascript, version-control

The company I work for develops and maintains multiple web-based products.  We have been pushing the teams to standardize and reuse 3rd party libraries of all kinds across prod. dev.  We use [Ivy](http://ant.apache.org/ivy/) to manage jar file dependencies for Java.  We use Python eggs in combination with custom build RPMs to manage Python dependencies.

I was wondering if there is a similar way to manage Javascript dependencies (e.g. jquery, raphaeljs, etc.).

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps you would like to check [RequireJS](http://requirejs.org/) or [Ender](http://enderjs.com/).

[Update]

As of today, 31 March 2017, there are a lot of different package managers and/or tools you could use to manage front-end libraries (npm, bower, rollup, etc.), but I currently found [Yarn](https://yarnpkg.com/en/) and [Webpack 2](https://webpack.js.org/) most interesting.

Comment: Is the latter link dead?

Comment: Seems they moved to a new domain name. I've updated the URL of Ender from http://ender.no.de/ to http://enderjs.com/